# Plotmath: concatenating (joining) a greek character to a roman character

Tags: r, plotmath

I'm trying to make a label which starts out with 'micrograms' except that it should be abbreviated.  I tried this:

```
plot(1, main = expression(mu~g~Toxin/gram~Fresh~Weight))
```

but it is rendered with a gap between mu and g which I don't want.  I realize I asked for that gap by using `~` but simply using `mug` is rendered as the word.  And, it would be better if the font of the mu and the g were more similar stylistically and in size if there is a trick for that, so that it looks less 'cobbled together' (which may be asking too much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
plot(1, main = expression(mu*g~Toxin/gram~Fresh~Weight))
```

Comment: Ah yes, I have trouble with the plotmath way of thinking: multiply means stick the characters together.  Thanks.

Comment: @BryanHanson I couldn't find the link where the connectors are specified.  But  `?plotmath` have examples that suggest the use of `*`

Comment: Actually the tilde and asterisk behaviors are described in the ?plotmath page along with the other infix-operators.

Comment: Hazy memory. Only the asterisk is separately described. The entry for `x ~~ y` says "put extra space between x and y" which might arguably be understood to imply that a single tilde was understood to put one space. Perhaps that's why it's so common to see people using things like: `expression(paste(mu,"g"))`